# charts.js not working properly in Ionic3

Tags: ionic2, chart.js, ionic3

In normal laptop view i am getting the chart well labeled and all the graph points are coming but when i open the app in moible view in browser it it does not fit well with the screen(as shown in image 2).. Can anyone please suggest some way to tackle  it and show all the points in mobile screen like the desktop(full screen) one.

In normal desktop view

[image]

in mobile view:

[image]

this is my code:

```
this.lineChart = new Chart(this.lineCanvas.nativeElement, {

            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: this.labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        data: this.priceArr,
                        spanGaps: true,
                    }
                ]
            }, options:{
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Price Rise/Fall'
                          }
                        }],
                        xAxes: [{
                          scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Time'
                          }
                        }]
                      }     
                    }


        });
```

Comment: To double check are you sure this is happening? What if you refresh the page while the dev console is still open?

Comment: Where is `data: this.priceArr,` defined? Both screenshots show what looks like non meaningful data and chart.js does sometimes behave a bit funny when you give it unexpected input. Can you try something "simple" to test like `data : [10,20,15,25]`?

Comment: @misha130 , In ionic refresh means starting the whole app again..on that it remains the same but on changing the screen size it is working properly.

Comment: @rory_za The data is correct ..since on changing the screen size the chart shows up properly.

Comment: What I meant is you shouldn't test screen resizing but screen sizes. If you say you hit F5(refresh) and its still not fixed then there's a problem with the library

Comment: Try using the methods "update()", "resize()" or "render()" on this.lineChart. This might not fix the underlying issue for rather force the chart to render as it does after you resize it.